# Laravel react-admin error orderBy not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, redux, react-admin

I am using react-admin with laravel, so what i am trying to do is sorting the data depending on the `created_at` field. what i do is to send the field name and order from the front to the server like this:

```
   case GET_LIST:
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort_field: JSON.stringify(field),
            sort_order: JSON.stringify(order),
            start_range: JSON.stringify((page - 1) * perPage),
            perPage: JSON.stringify(perPage),
            filter:JSON.stringify(params.filter)
        };
        return await instance
            .get(`${resource}/?${stringify(query)}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                let headers = res.headers;
                if (!headers['x-total-count']) {
                    throw new Error(
                        'The x-total-count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                    );
                }
                return {
                    data: res.data,
                    total: parseInt(headers['x-total-count'])
                };
            })
            .catch(er => {
                throw new Error(er);
            });
```

now on the server i am trying to get those value using request method but when i try to order the collection it's not working, here is server function for get all data:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $startrange = request('start_range');
        $perPage = request("perPage");
        $sortfield=request("sort_field");
        $sortorder=request("sort_order");
        $filter = request("filter");
        $posts = Post::orderBy($sortfield,$sortorder)->get()->toArray();;
        $result = array_slice($posts,$startrange,$perPage);
        return response($result)
    ->header('X-Total-Count', Post::all()->count());
}
```

and when i change the order By to static like this: `Post::orderBy("created_at","desc")->get()->toArray();`
the code work. Plus i tried to return `$sortfield` and `$sortorder` value which give the same value as the front!
please help fix this problem!

Edit:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '"created_at"' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` order by `"created_at"` asc) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '\"created_at\"' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` order by `\"created_at\"` asc) at C:\\Users\\Ralph\\Desktop\\ChatApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '\"created_at\"' in 'order clause' at C:\\Users\\Ralph\\Desktop\\ChatApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:326)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @guttume its a server error !

Comment: Yes, what is the error code and the message

Comment: server error code 500!

Comment: can you enable debugging in .env file and check please

Comment: @guttume is not really necessary to enable debugging in .env file if already in production, just check storage/logs, all error logs are stored there

Comment: yes whatever, the important thing is to get the actual error message to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: check edited post !

Comment: well i solved it by remove double quotes from the string like this:         `$sortfield=str_replace('"', '',request("sort_field"));
        $sortorder=str_replace('"', '', request("sort_order"));`